# OpenCover how to exclude tests with certain Category

Tags: opencover

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude certain tests that are marked by nunit category attribute and can't find it in documentation.

For instance: this test I want to be excluded:

```
    [Test]
    [Category("PerfomanceTests")]
    [Timeout(3000)]
    public void Some test()
    {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find how to exclude tests by category in [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) documentation as it is not a test runner.

OpenCover executes the program that runs your tests e.g. `nunit-console.exe` as such you need to look at [nunit documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.6.4) and the */include* and */exclude* switches and pass them to OpenCover via the `-targetargs:` switch along with other arguments that you may use.

```
-targetargs:"tests.dll /exclude:PerfomanceTests"
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what is needed and I just tested and it works. I though that this parameters has to be passed to console test runner, but as runner was a parameter for some reason I was expecting opencover to construct this parametes based on it's filters.